# can someone please explain what this part of the code means? setEmployeeNumber(num)

Tags: java, class, jgrasp

I was asked to write comments for a code but i dont understand exactly what the line setEmployeeNumber(num) is doing.why isnt it written setEmployeeNumber= number instead?And are all my other comments right? thanks in advance
                         /**
            Employee Class
            */

```
       public class Employee//creating employee class
     {//declaring fields
 private String name;             
 private String employeeNumber;   
private String hireDate;         


public Employee(String n, String num, String date)//construtor for Employee   class with param n,num,date
   {
    name = n; //assigning value of n to name
    setEmployeeNumber(num);//set employee 
    hireDate = date;//assign value of date to hireDate
   }

  public Employee()//non parametrized constructor
  {
  name = "";//set name to empty string
  employeeNumber = "";//set employeeNumber to empty string
  hireDate = "";//set hireDate to empty string
  }


  public void setName(String n)//setter with param n
  {
    name = n;//assign value of n to name
  }


     public void setEmployeeNumber(String e)//setter with param e
    {
     if (isValidEmpNum(e))//if string e is a valid employee number store the   value of e in employee number else set employee number to empty string
     employeeNumber = e;
  else
     employeeNumber = "";
    }


    public void setHireDate(String h)//setter with param h
   {
      hireDate = h;//assign the string h to hireDate
    }

       public String getName()//getter 
  {
  return name;//return value of name
  }


    public String getEmployeeNumber()//getter
     {
      return employeeNumber;//return value of employeeNumber
      }


    public String getHireDate()//getter
   {
      return hireDate;//return value of hireDate
   }

     private boolean isValidEmpNum(String e)//method to return true or false if employee number is valid or invalid
     {
      boolean status = true;//setting default status to True

     if (e.length() != 5)//if the length of string e does not equal to 5 then employee number is invalid,set status to false
     status = false;
  else
  {
     if ((!Character.isDigit(e.charAt(0))) ||//if the first char in string e is not a digit OR the 2nd char isnt a digit of the 3rd char is not a digit or the 4th char is not a dash OR the 5th char is not a letter than employee number is invalid,set status to false
         (!Character.isDigit(e.charAt(1))) ||
         (!Character.isDigit(e.charAt(2))) ||
         (e.charAt(3) != '-')              ||
         (!Character.isLetter(e.charAt(4))))
           status = false;
  }

  return status;//returing true or false
```

}

```
    public String toString()//Method to returns a string representation of the object
   {
     String str = "Name: " + name + "\nEmployee Number: ";//making a new string called str 

  if (employeeNumber == "")//if employeeNuber is invalid
     str += "INVALID EMPLOYEE NUMBER";//add  "INVALID EMPLOYEE NUMBER" to string str
  else
     str += employeeNumber;//add value of employeeNumber to string str

  str += ("\nHire Date: " + hireDate);//add "\nHire Date: " and value of hireDate to string str
  return str;//returning the string str
    }
  }
```

Comment: You haven't posted the code of `setEmployeeNumber`... But, judging by the name, it probably assigns `num` to the `employeeNumber` variable.

Comment: "creating employee class" is wrong. It is **declaring** the employee class

Comment: as a side note- you are over over commenting. putting a comment like 'assigning value of n to name' to a line that says `name = n;` is completely redundant. Your comments should not explain how java works, they should explain the logic of the code

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a method. The comment should really no different than the others in the constructor, but if you want to be technical...

```
setEmployeeNumber(num); // calls the method that sets the employee number to the value of num
```

---

Assuming somewhere in your code you have this

```
public void setEmployeeNumber(String num)    //setter with param num
{
    employeeNumber= num;     //assign value of num to employeeNumber
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `setEmployeeNumber(String e)` is most likely used to set a Unique Alpha-Numeric number (Containing A-Z & 0-9). All you would have to comment is something like `//assign employeeNumber to e`.